# Collapse array of sets to single set in Julia

Tags: set, julia

How do I collapse an array of sets to a single set containing all unique set elements in the following way?

```
Array_of_sets = Set{String}[Set(["EUR", "GBP", "USD"]), Set(["AUD"])]
# do something to Array_of_sets which produces
Set{String}(["EUR", "GBP", "USD", "AUD"])
```

`union`, `vcat` and `unique` do not seem to work in this case.

Comment: The type of the array is automatically inferred, so you can just write: `Array_of_sets = [Set(["EUR", "GBP", "USD"]), Set(["AUD"])]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So sets are already unique:

```
julia> S = Set(["a", "b"])
 Set(["b", "a"])
julia> push!(S, "a")
 Set(["b", "a"])
```

Therefore, no `unique` needed:

```
julia> A = Set{String}[Set(["EUR", "GBP", "USD"]), Set(["EUR", "AUD"])]
julia> reduce(union!, A)
 Set(["EUR", "GBP", "AUD", "USD"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the sets to arrays, and vcat them:

```
Array_of_sets = Set{String}[Set(["EUR", "GBP", "USD"]), Set(["AUD"])]
Array_of_arrays = map(collect, Array_of_sets)
Set(vcat(Array_of_arrays...))
> Set{String}(["EUR", "GBP", "USD", "AUD"])
```

Edit: But then I'm not as clever as @stillearningsomething

Comment: Shouldn't the nice `Set` properties be used?  Mapping them to arrays for processing throws away all the "set-ness".